# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Any ideas why?

```
var formData = new FormData($('#my-form').get(0));

var prm_add = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/gateway/add',
            data: {data : formData}
        });

prm_add.done(function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
```

Comment: What makes you sure the error is here?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting processData as false, also pass fomData as the data object don't create another data object

```
var prm_add = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/gateway/add',
    processData: false,
    data: formData
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ARZv/)

[processData](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set
>   this option to false.

Use [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#append%28%29) to add additional data to formData

Read: [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: I need to create another data object so I can push things to it.

Comment: @panthro you can add additional values to formData itself

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, I'm getting nothing through now in my php script.

Comment: @panthro not a PHP guy so can't don't know how to handle it in PHP